# How can I fix knit tables in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have an RMarkdown document that has some data wrangling parts within it. I can see all tables calculated as they should look in RStudio once computed. However, once I knit to HTML, I can see all the outputs, however some tables look very messy. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? Refer to below picture.

**Why do the two columns below not appear next to the other ones in one line?**

[image]

Comment: that is just the print width, `options(width = 100)` or something bigger. if the rows interleave, then you should increase the width of the table, print like the answer below, or use a scroll bar for the overflow

Answer (score 1):

You could try a few things, starting with round down some of the decimals so everything fits.

1. If you need the decimals you could try printing it with `knitr::kable(table)`. This will help with the tables looking messy.
2. For even more control there is a library `kableExtra` that has a function `kable_styling`:

```
library(kableExtra)

table %>% 
  knitr::kable() %>% # you can control column names, row names, rounding of table here
  kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options = c("scale_down") # will fit table
```

`kable_styling` has an argument `full_width` for HTML tables too. For more information on this library see this [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html#HTML_Only_Features)